# Inefficient parsing of Vertex and Index data, looking for more efficient methods

Tags: arrays, swift, scenekit, metal

I wrote a method to parse an array containing vertex data. The goal of the method was to produce a new array of unique vertices and a new index from that data.

This is the struct I used to store the vertices in the array.

```
struct Vertex: Hashable {
    var x, y, z,
    nx, ny, nz,
    s, t: Float

    var hashValue: Int {
        return "\(self.x),\(self.y),\(self.z),\(self.nx),\(self.ny),\(self.nz),\(self.s),\(self.t),".hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Vertex, rhs: Vertex) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
}
```

And this is the method I used to create the array of unique vertices and new index. The first argument of the method takes an array with the vertex data already ordered by the original index.

```
func makeVertexIndex(_ array: [Float]) -> ([Vertex], [Int]) {
    var counter = 0
    var indexCounter = 0
    var holder = [Float]()
    var vertices = [Vertex]()
    var index = [Int]()

    for i in array {
        counter += 1

        if counter == 8 {
            counter = 0
            holder.append(i)
            let vertex = Vertex(x: holder[0], y: holder[1], z: holder[2],
                                nx: holder[3], ny: holder[4], nz: holder[5],
                                s: holder[6], t: holder[7])

            if vertices.contains(vertex) {
                guard let match = vertices.index(of: vertex) else { continue }
                index.append(match)
            } else {
                vertices.append(vertex)
                index.append(indexCounter)
                indexCounter += 1
            }

            holder.removeAll()
        } else {
            holder.append(i)
        }
    }

    return (vertices, index)
}
```

I was able to successfully parse lower triangle count meshes, but when I try to run this on higher triangle count meshes it took over an hour to run.

I'm pretty new to coding, Swift is my first language, but I suspect it shouldn't take this long to do this task and I probably just wrote my method really inefficiently or maybe there's a completely different way I could approach this problem.

Anyhow I'd appreciate any help I could get. Thanks for reading.

**Update 1:**
I re-wrote my method to create the vertex array first then change to it to a set to make the values unique and back to an array then ran it through the vertexArray loop looking for matches in the unique vertices array. This version of the method cut the process time from 21 seconds on my test mesh to about 12 seconds.

```
func makeVertexIndex(_ array: [Float]) -> ([Vertex], [Int]) {
    var counter = 0
    var holder = [Float]()
    var vertexArray = [Vertex]()
    var vertices = [Vertex]()
    var index = [Int]()

    for i in array {
        counter += 1

        if counter == 8 {
            counter = 0
            holder.append(i)
            let vertex = Vertex(x: holder[0], y: holder[1], z: holder[2],
                                nx: holder[3], ny: holder[4], nz: holder[5],
                                s: holder[6], t: holder[7])

            vertexArray.append(vertex)

            holder.removeAll()
        } else {
            holder.append(i)
        }
    }

    let vertexSet = Set(vertexArray)
    vertices = Array(vertexSet)

    for v in vertexArray {
        guard let match = vertices.index(of: v) else { continue }
        index.append(match)
    }

    return (vertices, index)
}
```

**Update 2:**

Here are my updated struct and method after implementing some of the recommended solutions.

Struct:

```
struct Vertex: Hashable {
    var x, y, z,
    nx, ny, nz,
    s, t: Float

    var hashValue: Int {
        return "\(self.x),\(self.y),\(self.z),\(self.nx),\(self.ny),\(self.nz),\(self.s),\(self.t)".hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Vertex, rhs: Vertex) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.x == rhs.x) && (lhs.y == rhs.y) && (lhs.z == rhs.z) && (lhs.nx == rhs.nx) &&
            (lhs.ny == rhs.ny) && (lhs.nz == rhs.nz) && (lhs.s == rhs.s) && (lhs.t == rhs.t)
    }
}
```

Method:

```
    func makeVertexIndex(_ array: [Float]) -> ([Vertex], [Int]) {
        var vertexArray = [Vertex]()
        vertexArray.reserveCapacity(array.count / 8)

        var vertices = [Vertex]()
        var index = [Int]()

        // Creating an array of Vertex from an array containing 
        // position/normal/texcoord in correct order.
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: 8) {
            let vertex = Vertex(x: array[i], y: array[i + 1], z: array[i + 2],
                                nx: array[i + 3], ny: array[i + 4], nz: array[i + 5],
                                s: array[i + 6], t: array[i + 7])

            vertexArray.append(vertex)
        }

        // Making the Vertex array unique by converting to set and back to array.
        let vertexSet = Set(vertexArray)
        vertices = Array(vertexSet)

        // Making new index by finding the matching vertex in the 
        // unique vertex array and adding that array index to the new index
        for v in vertexArray {
            guard let match = vertices.index(of: v) else { continue }
            index.append(match)
        }

        return (vertices, index)
    }
```

After trying out various parts of the recommended solutions the method was able to process a model with 70K triangles in 13 minutes, previously it took over an hour and a half.

So this was a huge improvement, appreciate all the solutions so far, going to keep this open for maybe a day or two to see if any other recommendations come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why your == code compares hashes rather than each property? i.e.

```
static func ==(lhs: Vertex, rhs: Vertex) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.x == rhs.x) && (lhs.y == rhs.y) && (lhs.z == rhs.z) &&
        (lhs.nx == rhs.nx) && ...etc
}
```

Then if `lhs.x` is not equal to `rhs.x`, the code will fail quickly and move on to the next. Currently you're having to create a hash value again and again. Alternatively, you could speed up your current code by calculating the hash once in the constructor (and, say, making all the properties `private(set)` like in the simplified example below).

```
struct Vertex {
    private(set) var x, y: Float
    let hash: Int

    init(x: Float, y: Float) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        hash = "\(x),\(y)".hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Vertex, rhs: Vertex) -> Bool {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x
    }
}

let vertex = Vertex(x: 1.0, y: 2.0)
print(vertex.hash)
```

Comment: I'm currently testing out your solution, so far just making changes to the func == has made a huge difference, went from 12 seconds down to 3 seconds. OMG Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm going to try to implement the second part of your post now, getting an error saying I'm not conforming to hashable when I try to remove the var hashValue: Int { ... } part of my struct

Comment: I think he made a small typo there, the variable has to be called hashValue to conform to Hashable.

Comment: I was able to implement the initializer for the struct without receiving any errors, but whenever I run method to import the 3d model, it doesn't show anything. But I see the your logic with the initializer, I'll try fiddling with it some more to see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to end up with a new set of Vertices, and a set of indices. If the new set of vertices contains a duplicate, remove that from the list of vertices, and double the index of the duplicate. Judging from your first function. Your second only added an index when there was a match. Which did you mean?

From the first.. if you have V1 V2 V3 V4, and V4 = V1, you want indices [0,0,1,2].

Is this correct? I would clean that up by iterating over the float array 8 at a time, then determine if there are duplicates, if so, figure out which are duplicates and then create your final two arrays. Here's my take..

```
func makeVertexIndex(_ array: [Float]) -> ([Vertex], [Int]) {

    var newVertices = [Vertex]()
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: array.count, by: 8) {
        newVertices.append(Vertex(x: array[i], y: array[i + 1], z: array[i + 2],
                               nx: array[i + 3], ny: array[i + 4], nz: array[i + 5],
                               s: array[i + 6], t: array[i + 7]))

    }


    if newVertices.count > Set(newVertices).count {
        var uniqueVertices = [Vertex]()
        var indices = [Int]()

        var vertexIndex = [Vertex: Int]()
        var count = 0

        for vertex in newVertices {
            if let existingVertex = vertexIndex[vertex] {
                indices.append(existingVertex)
            } else {
                vertexIndex[vertex] = count
                uniqueVertices.append(vertex)
                count += 1
            }
        }

        return (uniqueVertices, indices.sorted())

    } else {
        return (newVertices, [Int](0..<newVertices.count))

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my code was not very clear. Basically in the last part of my method, the vertexArray loop is used to create the new index.  The vertexArray contains all the vertex including duplicates, in the correct order. So every time it finds a match in the unique vertex array it stores the index value to be used later in the SCNGeometryElement object.

Comment: And thanks for taking the time to post, I'm going to try out your solution and see what results I get.

Comment: No sweat. The code above filtered the duplicates out of the vertex array, and returned unique vertices and an array of indices, adding another entry into indices whenever a duplicate or triplicate, etc, was found, of the index of the first copy.

Comment: that method stride(from:to:by:) is so cool, I wasn't aware of that!